# Proof that Reidemeister torsion doesn't depend on cellular structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I need to find a proof (or the sketch) of the topological invariance of Reidemeister torsion, when studying lens spaces, it is often computed but I can't find a proof of it.

Comment: Is Reidemeister torsion a special case of Whitehead torsion? Chapman has proved the latter in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373556?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: @ConnorMalin I think it is, I was searching for a proof without that much generality